# duplicate key update with select

Tags: mysql, duplicates, insert, append, key

I have gone through several posts but unable to find the exact fix. Here is what I want -

```
Table1 - column1, column2, column3, amount as column4
Table2 - column1, column2, column3, amount as column4
```

I am using below code which works fine for insert, but for update, it doesnt update amount column

Below is the code

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1,column2, column3, amount)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, sum(amount) 
FROM table1 
where column5 != '' and column5 != 'null' and column7 = 'good' 
group by column1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=SELECT sum(amount) FROM table1 where column5 != '' and column5 != 'null' and column7 = 'good' group by column1;
```

I know the error is for update part because when I make `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=0` this works and all the rows are updated as 0

What am I doing wrong for update part.

Thank you for the help in advance.

I want update query part to get worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery is not allowed on `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, here is a way to do it without recalculating the total amount by using a derived table that enables references to columns from `GROUP BY` queries :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1,column2, column3, amount)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, SUM(amount) AS _amount
  FROM table1
  WHERE column5 != '' and column5 != 'null' and column7 = 'good' 
  GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
) AS S
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = _amount;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jCuLWTut)

Answer (score 0):

Put `()` around the subquery. Like below:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = (SELECT sum(amount) FROM table1 where column5 != '' and column5 != 'null' and column7 = 'good' group by column1);
```